Export / Apply Animation from Geometry Nodes
Is it possible to either:

export the result of a Geometry Nodes Animation (preferrably to .glb),
apply a change made in Geometry Nodes as Shape Key
at least ‚bake‘ the Animation to Keyframes

Re. 1. maybe there is a way to export and reimport the animation in different formats to achieve a baked-in version of an animated glb-object?
Re. 2. I am aware that since Geometry nodes is able to generate new Geometry, there is no simple Apply to Shape Key Option, but if it is used to just displace existing geo maybe there is a way to transfer the info with one of the ‚Edit‘-Modifiers from an animated GN-object to another static one with the same topology? But even then i am unsure if there is a way to apply that to a Shape Key?
Re. 3. If its not possible to use Shape Keys, can you maybe transfer the position info to somehow bake/apply the Animation to regular Keyframes?
Any hacky ways are welcome! :)
Best,
todesdigga
